# Saving array of strings to plist

Tags: objective-c

```
1.   if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
2.    {
3.        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
4.        // files and directories selected.
5.        NSArray* urls = [openDlg URLs];

6.        // Loop through all the files and process them.
7.        for(int i = 0; i < [urls count]; i++ )
8.        {

                    // this fails to update the .plist file
9.          //[_sourceFiles addObject: [urls objectAtIndex:i] ];

                    // plist file updates successfully
10.         [_sourceFiles addObject:@"file://localhost/Users/Bill/Documents/" ];

11.         NSLog(@"%@", [urls objectAtIndex:i]);

12.        }

13.         [_myTable reloadData];
14.     }
```

_sourceFiles is an an mutable array of strings that gets saved to a .plist file. The curious thing is that WriteToFile to a .plist file fails with 9. but succeeds with 10. even though both 9. and 10. return strings.

This has puzzled me for a few days now: Using the strings returned by open File Dialog always fails to update the .plist file and, yet, if I supply string literals instead, updating the .plist file always succeeds.

Also, is there any way to get the WriteToFile for an NSMutablearray to display the nature of the error?

Hoping that someone can help and plenty of thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to convert the URL into a string first. Lookup Xcode Doc for NSURL and use a method that does that accordingly.

Comment: you don't show the code that saves the mutable array, b.t.w.

Comment: … so line 9. would possibly look like this: [_sourceFiles addObject: [[urls objectAtIndex:i]path] ];

Comment: Thanks DigiMonk. [_sourceFiles addObject: [[urls objectAtIndex:i]path] ]; worked.  [_sourceFiles addObject: [[urls objectAtIndex:i]absoluteString] ]; worked also.